# Fourier Transform diagonalizes time-invariant convolution operators

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

I got the following paragraph from the book "A wavelet tour of signal processing" chapter one, page 2.

**The Fourier transform is everywhere in physics and mathematics because it diagonalizes time-invariant convolution operators.  It rules over linear time-invariant signal
processing, the building blocks of which are frequency filtering operators.**

How is it (illustrated) formulated mathematically?

Comment: this is just the statement that the Fourier transform $\hat{C}(\omega,\omega')$ of the integral operator $C(t,t')$ -- if it is only a function of $t-t'$ (time translation invariant), is of the form $\hat{C}(\omega,\omega')=f(\omega)\delta(\omega-\omega')$, so only nonvanishing on the "diagonal" where $\omega=\omega'$.